# Codeigniter redirect() adds a question mark in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I am using CI's redirect() function in my web app, the redirect() is adding a question mark in the url which is creating an issue and I am unable to fix it. Tried editing the htaccess code, but no luck.

Appreciate every one's help, TIA

Comment: Codeigniter is very popular for its User Guide! Make sure you have checked it , if not please refer this link first https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check config.php, if enable_query_strings = true you will have ? in urls. Should be:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = false;
```

Comment: Are you sure this forces a `?` even when there's no GET data?

Comment: How are using the redirect function? post your code?

Comment: well, I am in a situation where I need $config['enable_query_strings'] = true; .. how to fix the ? issue i this case...

Answer (score -2):

This Will solve adding question mark for site_url function in codeigniter 3.01

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```